# Disable default setting permanently for all future projects

Tags: intellij-idea

I never use the spell check inspection in IntelliJ. I know I can disable it in my project by going to `Preferences > Editor > Inspections`, but as soon as I open or create a new project this inspection is enabled again.

How do I change the default set of enabled inspections in IntelliJ such that I can disable an inspection for the current *and* all future projects?

Answer (score 1):

File | Other Settings | Default Settings | Inspections